# How to Create EventCommadExecuter Event for Control Programatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created the `InvokeCommandAction` [event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808950/how-to-create-an-event-trigger-for-control-programmatically) programmatically like this link.
But I don't know how to create the below event programmatically,

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">                                    
               <cmd:EventCommandExecuter Command="{Binding AddGridCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I have tried like below, but null is returned in the `EventCommandExecuter` Command. Please anyone suggest me to achieve this.

```
void SetGridTrigger(Grid itemsControl, string bindingPath)
{                     
    var binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath(bindingPath) };
    ICommand DropCommand = (binding as ICommand);
    var eventCommandExecuter = new EventCommandExecuter { Command = DropCommand };

    BindingOperations.SetBinding(eventCommandExecuter, InvokeCommandAction.CommandProperty, binding);

    var eventTrigger = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger { EventName = "Drop" };
    eventTrigger.Actions.Add(eventCommandExecuter);

    var triggers = Interaction.GetTriggers(itemsControl);
    triggers.Add(eventTrigger);
}
```

**EventCommandExecuter**

```
 public class EventCommandExecuter : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
    {
        #region Constructors

        public EventCommandExecuter()
            : this(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        {
        }

        public EventCommandExecuter(CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Culture = culture;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        #region Command

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventCommandExecuter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion

        #region EventArgsConverterParameter

        public object EventArgsConverterParameter
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(EventArgsConverterParameterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EventArgsConverterParameterProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty EventArgsConverterParameterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EventArgsConverterParameter", typeof(object), typeof(EventCommandExecuter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion

        public IValueConverter EventArgsConverter { get; set; }

        public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

        #endregion

        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            var cmd = Command;

            if (cmd != null)
            {
                var param = parameter;

                if (EventArgsConverter != null)
                {
                    param = EventArgsConverter.Convert(parameter, typeof(object), EventArgsConverterParameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }

                if (cmd.CanExecute(param))
                {
                    cmd.Execute(param);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand very well the reason of this setting: ICommand DropCommand = (binding as ICommand);

Comment: What is EventCommandExecuter? Why aren't you using the InvokeCommandAction class as-is?

Comment: @mm8, I want routed event in viewmodel. So I used EventCommandExecuter. Please refer my updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the `EventCommandExecuter.CommandProperty` to your binding path:

```
EventCommandExecuter eventCommandExecuter = new EventCommandExecuter();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(eventCommandExecuter, EventCommandExecuter.CommandProperty,
    new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath(bindingPath) });

EventTrigger eventTrigger = new EventTrigger { EventName = "Drop" };
eventTrigger.Actions.Add(eventCommandExecuter);
Interaction.GetTriggers(itemsControl).Add(eventTrigger);
```

Comment: Very nice eye, i didn't noted it, in my answer i focused on wrong binding, without see that mistake.